# Copy over filtered files from another sheet

Tags: excel

i am trying to copy some cells from one sheet to another which is filtered but excel returns this error:

this is the main sheet with the filtered applied over all rows

[image]

an this is the second sheet that contains the rows that i want to copy to the main sheet

[image]

and finally this is the error returned.

[image]

i tried selecting visible cells in the main sheet but doesn't works :(

please could you tell me any way to reach this?

thank you very much!!

Comment: Hi Vityata,  i don't undestand your question. Please could you  clarify??

Comment: Hi Vityata, perhaps its a mistake from my side, i needed how to solve this point with the excel tools, without any code, if this is not the correct site for post this type of doubts, im sorry. BR.